# TCPConnection IO Exception web application

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm trying to read datafroma device.
The following codeworks fine on a Desktop application.
When I put it in a Web Application,it gives IO Exception.
I've turned off FireWall,
When deployed

```
Client inherits from TcpClientPlus
                using (FaceId Client = new FaceId(textBoxDeviceIP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBoxDevicePort.Text)))
{
    Client.SecretKey =textBoxSecretKey.Text.Trim();
    string Answer;
    FaceId_ErrorCode ErrorCode = Client.Execute(textBoxCommand.Text, out Answer, DeviceCodePage);
    if (ErrorCode == FaceId_ErrorCode.Success)
    {
        textBoxAnswer.Text = Answer;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Code: " + ErrorCode.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
        I've found out the reason: another connection was open at the same time.
```

Also, I've turned on the firewall & it worked fine.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the IOException provide some additional info?

Comment: I've found out the reason: another connection was open at the same time.
Thanks a lot